# How to directly interact with already deployed smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I am tasked with interacting with a function in a smart contract that has already been deployed. I know the contract address and the function signature and I have a solution that uses interfaces. However, this function I am interacting with then sends an NFT to `msg.sender` which in this case is the contract with the `interface` solution as opposed to my personal account.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

interface ITargetContract {
    function addWhitelist(bytes32 _something, string memory _id)
        external;
}

contract MyContract {
    function addWhitelist(
        address _t,
        bytes32 _something,
        string memory _id
    ) public {
        ITargetContract(_t).addWhitelist(_something, _id);
    }
}
```

So to avoid this NFT being sent to my contract, can I interact with the deployed contract directly with my personal account if I only know the contract address and function signature?

Answer (score 1):

The only case when `msg.sender` is relayed is `delegatecall`. However, it also uses storage of the caller contract (and not of the called one), so it's mostly used in proxy contracts.

There's no way to both relay the `msg.sender` and use the storage of the called contract.

---

Assuming the target contract implements the [ERC721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard, you can implement the `onERC721Received()` function and resend the token to the end user after you've received it.

```
contract MyContract {
    mapping (string => address) tokenUsers;

    function addWhitelist(
        address _t,
        bytes32 _something,
        string memory _id
    ) public {
        // store the end user address by the token ID
        tokenUsers[_id] = msg.sender;
        ITargetContract(_t).addCandidateIdToWhitelist(_something, _id);
    }

    function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external returns(bytes4) {
        // resend the token from your contract to the user
        ITargetContract.safeTransferFrom(
            address(this),
            tokenUsers[_tokenId],
            // TODO: transfer functions accept the token ID as uint, not as string
            _stringToUint(_tokenId)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Petr, thank you for your response. This link shows my implementation with interfaces (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xb6c5ad71ffe74d903a3950b97601ec8182d5b4a3f62fb58a2953c93892d19410), and then an implementation where it appears people are interacting with the contract (0x006eCb9efFA194df5ce192AF1e15eFBaa8a3c87b) directly(https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe0be331f78a698e5cd777adf0322a6eca61263a003064135b367d8d266e2b6f2). I just wonder how they did it without a contract in the middle?